# adding outline for image in qgraphicsitem with different image resolution

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

Im trying to paint a image with outline in a qgraphicsitem . this image will have different resolution (640x380, 1190* 780, 320 *410)  and i have to draw a constant 4px outline irrespective to the image width and height . i tried to take the percent of the image geometry but for different size of image the outline is changing . for higher  resolution it looks thin and for smaller value thin line .

```
QFont segoeFont("Segoe Regular");
    segoeFont.setPointSize(10);
    painter->setFont(segoeFont);
    painter->setRenderHints(QPainter::TextAntialiasing);
    painter->setBrush(QColor(69,69,69));
    if(meIsSelected)
    {
        painter->setBrush(QColor(65, 167, 243));
        QPen pen(QColor(65, 167, 243), 2);
        pen.setCosmetic(true);
    }

    painter->drawRect (this->boundingRect ());
    painter->drawImage (QPoint(0,0), mePixmap);
```

and my boundingRect()

return mePixmap.rect ().adjusted (-4, -4, 4, 4);

this item is shown in view with fitInview

```
void GraphicsView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(event);
    fitInView(this->scene()->sceneRect (),Qt::KeepAspectRatio) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a constant 4px outline and the screen resolution is changing, what you're seeing is correct.

A 4px outline will, naturally look smaller with a higher resolution. In theory, if the resolution were just 4 pixels wide, it would take up the whole width of the screen, but with an 8px wide resolution, the 4px line would cover just half the screen. In both cases, the outline is still 4px.

If your screen resolution is the same and it's just the image resolution that's changing, then you need to show your code of how you're trying to render the outline.

Comment: The code you've posted shows that you call painter->setBrush, then create a pen, but do not set the pen to the painter. Also, if you're returning a boundingRect of the image + 4px around the image, I would have thought you'd need to call painter->drawImage(QPoint(4,4), mePixmap);